# examine the convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n*10^{log(logn)}}$$ 
I have to examine
$\sum{a_n}$ so I used Cauchy's condensation test and I got:
$$b_n=\frac{2^n}{2^n*10^{log(log2^n)}}$$so 
$$b_n=\frac{2^n}{2^n*10^{log(log2)^n}}$$ 
later I used Cauchy's root test:
$$lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{2^n}{2^n*10^{log(log2)^n}}}$$
$$lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{10^{log(log2)}}}$$

right now I have to check if  $$\frac{1}{10^{log(log2)}}>1$$

I know that it is but can't prove it.

Comment: $10^{\ln\ln2}\approx0.43$.

Answer (score 0):

$\log 2$ is around $0.7,$ so its log is negative so your left hand side is BIGGER than $1.$

Comment: ok it's bigger but how to prove it

Comment: @Kacper: What???? Don't you have a calculator?

Comment: I can't use calculator I have to prove it

Comment: My answer is the proof (actually, if you don't want to use $0.7,$ just say $2 < e.$)